# python pdb equivalent of perldb methods callable?

Tags: python, perl, debugging

I am used to Perl's debugger `m` `methods callable` function so that during debugging, I can do:

```
m $self
```

And I will get a list of methods associated to the object at that point.

Is there an equivalent to that in `python-2.7.5 -m pdb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to query the current object (`self`), use:

```
(Pdb) dir(self)
```

Otherwise, you can install `ipdb`, which gives you an IPython-based debugger. There, you get autocompletion:

```
ipdb> self.<TAB>
```